# How to make Sublime Text 3 take user input?

Tags: ubuntu, c++

I tried <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> when no user input was required and works just fine.

But when I had user input in my program, it shows me a “segmentation fault.”

How do I make it take user input?

EDIT :

I am looking for a way to open to the terminal and run my c++ code(which requires user input) in sublime text 3.

My code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

  int var ; 
  cout<<"\nvar : " ; 
  cin>>var ; 
  cout<<endl<<var ; 

}
```

I tried out this as a build system

```
{
"cmd": ["g++ ${file} -o ${file_base_name}"], 
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.c++",
"shell": true,
"variants":
[
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "cmd": ["konsole --hold --nofork -e ${file_path}/./${file_base_name}"],
        "shell": true
    }
]
}
```

[Which I got from here](https://gist.github.com/PhilCK/1566100)

But it gives me this error message

```
/bin/sh: 1: konsole: not found
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 127]
```

How do I open up the terminal instead of Konsole which is for Kubuntu?

Comment: If you get a seg fault you should report a bug with the ST developer. Super User is not the place to talk about apparent bugs in software. Or is the segmentation fault happening in your program? If that's the case, it's a programming issue, which would be better suited for [SO] — if you can show your source code, of course. Can you please clarify?

Comment: My bad @slhck. Actually I am trying to build and run some c++ code. 
I tried building and running some basic programs which require taking input from the user and it was not running. 
I am looking for something by which I can give input to sublime text.
Can we do that?

Comment: Well, you need to be more specific. I would go to [SO], show the actual code you are using, and then describe what happens (i.e. show the complete command line output). Also make sure to mention your build version of ST3.

Comment: Now you're not talking about a segmentation fault anymore in the second part of the question?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install

> konsole

first. if you're running ubuntu, install with this command `sudo apt-get install konsole`